How can i resolve invalid request for google oath on expo-go?
Im new on react native and i'm trying to implement google oath without firebase on an expo app.
It's working on web,and android apk but when i try to test on android and ios via expo go i got invalid request error 400. I set up all the credentials good in the google console.
I tried everything, i m stuck.
Thanks for help, sorry for the indentation
my app.json
{
"expo": {
"plugins": [
  [
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
    {
      "iosUrlScheme": "com.googleusercontent.apps.871816637044-***"
    }
  ]
],
"name": "google-sign-in",
"slug": "google-sign-in",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*"
],
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.alexx.googlesignin",
  "infoPlist": {
    "CFBundleURLTypes": [
      {
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
          "com.googleusercontent.apps.871816637044-***"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "package": "com.alexx.googlesignin"
},
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"scheme": "com.alexx.googlesignin",
"extra": {
  "eas": {
    "projectId": "0c0362e2-936e-4029-afbb-ee123b9a93f0"
  }
},
"runtimeVersion": {
  "policy": "appVersion"
},
"updates": {
  "url": "https://u.expo.dev/0c0362e2***"
}
}
}

my app.js:
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
export default function App() {
const [token, setToken] = useState("");
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
webClientId: "871816637044-ejvm***",
expoClientId: "871816637044-ta7mh***",
iosClientId: "871816637044-esek***",
androidClientId: "871816637044-taf44***",
useProxy: false
});
useEffect(() => {
handleEffect();
}, [response, token]);
async function handleEffect() {
const user = await getLocalUser();
console.log("user", user);
if (!user) {
  if (response?.type === "success") {
    // setToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
    getUserInfo(response.authentication.accessToken);
  }
 } else {
  setUserInfo(user);
  console.log("loaded locally");
 }
 }
 const getLocalUser = async () => {
 const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
 if (!data) return null;
 return JSON.parse(data);
 };

 const getUserInfo = async (token) => {
 if (!token) return;
 try {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    }
  );
  const user = await response.json();
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", JSON.stringify(user));
  setUserInfo(user);
  } catch (error) {
  // Add your own error handler here
  }
  };

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  {!userInfo ? (
    <Button
      title="Sign in with Google"
      disabled={!request}
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      {userInfo?.picture && (
        <Image source={{ uri: userInfo?.picture }} style={styles.image} />
      )}
      <Text style={styles.text}>Email: {userInfo.email}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        Verified: {userInfo.verified_email ? "yes" : "no"}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Name: {userInfo.name}</Text>
      {/* <Text style={styles.text}>{JSON.stringify(userInfo, null, 2)}</Text> */}
    </View>
  )}
  <Button
    title="remove local store"
    onPress={async () => await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@user")}
  />
</View>
);
}

expo credentials

There's no comma on param useproxy, try add it..

Afaik you also need to enable custom url scheme on google play cloud console when creating the oath

– bagi2info.com i did it for my expo credentials

Another one to check is sha1 or md5 value need to match with bundle id, check with eas credential

please edit your question and include your code not an image of your code

@bagi2info.com thanks for ur answer, it's working when i build apk on android simulator but i still get error for expo go app
